# Extbase storagePid with levelfield

Tags: typo3, typoscript, extbase, typo3-6.1.x

I try to set the the `storagePid` of an extbase plugin by using `levelfield` like this:

```
plugin.tx_myext.persistence.storagePid = TEXT
plugin.tx_myext.persistence.storagePid.data= levelfield: -1, storage_pid, slide
```

Using the `storage_pid` of the current page is no problem:

```
plugin.tx_myext.persistence.storagePid = TEXT
plugin.tx_myext.persistence.storagePid.data= page:storage_pid
```

But I want to use `levelfield` to improve the usability of an extension. Thus you only would have to setup the `storage_pid` in the root page and include the default typoscript setup for the extension, which uses `levelfield`, into the root template...

Does anybody have a clue why `levelfield` is here not working?

Answer (score 1):

Not all fields can be used by default with levelfield. The fields that can be used on scratch are defined in `$TYPO3_CONF_VARS["FE"]["addRootLineFields"]`

To add another field simply add

```php
$GLOBALS["TYPO3_CONF_VARS"]["FE"]["addRootLineFields"] .= ",storage_pid";
```

in `typo3conf/ext_tables.php` or in the `ext_tables.php` of your extension.

Comment: Unfortunately `storage_pid` is already part of the rootline per default checkout https://github.com/TYPO3/TYPO3.CMS/blob/0d69f740086120ffee7409001f7090520ab9734c/typo3/sysext/core/Classes/Utility/RootlineUtility.php#L96. This can easily tested by using `levefield: -1, storage_pid, slider` just in a page template somewhere. Which works without any problems unlike the `storagePid` property in extbase.